# Calculating preferred height based on actual Codenameone's component width (2)

Tags: java, codenameone

Currently I'm creating a codename one component for which the height depends on the width. Codename one (Shai Almog) replied that this is not easy to do, the layout algorithms aren't intended to handle this requirement. See the original question here. A suggestion was given to use the approach in the Codename one `TextArea` component, but apparently this approach was not without issues itself.

No I would like to solve this by a different approach. I was wondering if people could give feedback on whether this would work or not. The basic idea is the assumption that the width and height of a `Form` component, as being the highest component in hierarchy, won't depend on a layout manager but directly on the display. And thus has fixed dimensions. The Form has a child `Container` contentPane that I'm assuming then also has fixed size. Then we can create a custom `LayoutManager` to use this information. Say we extend from a `BoxLayout` and overload its methods `layoutContainer(Container c)` and `getPreferredSize(Container c)` to use this info, using `c.getParent().getParent() instanceof Form` to know width and height (depending and for custom resizable components create methods such as `getPrefferedWForHeight(int height)` or an initializing method `setFixedWidth(int width)` that affects the usual `getPrefferredH()` and `getPrefferredW()` calls.

Nicest would be to extend components using methods such as `hasFixedWidth()` (or to combine width and height in one call `hasFixedDimension(int axis)`) and `widthDependsOnHeight()` that would make the `BoxLayout` independent on hard coded class names, but it look like it can't be done as replacing Codename one components using

```
UIBuilder.registerCustomComponent("Container", nl.localhost.Container.class);
UIBuilder.registerCustomComponent("Form", nl.localhost.Form.class);
```

appears not to have effect.

I haven't thought much about scrolling or rotating devices (and thus repainting Forms) but I don't think it will give a problem. Would the approach above work?

Best wishes Marc K

Comment: Maybe. Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 0):

What we do quite often in Components is to set their preferred width to `Display.getInstance().getWidth()` which "hints" to the layout manager about our intentions.

When the device is rotated `calcPreferredSize()` is invoked again and the display width would be the physical device height.

The registration code that you used is relevant to the old GUI builder. I don't exactly see why its related to the question at hand.

Comment: Ok so again use `calcPreferredSize()`. Thanks for the `Display.getInstance().getWidth()Display.getInstance().getWidth()` tip, this should be enough information to finish. Marc K.